# Web Интерфейс для ftp сервера

Tags: веб-сервер, ftp-сервер, armbian-linux

Имеется приставка android-tv с установленый Armbian на неё, а так же старенький Nas. Необходимо развернуть на приставке ftp сервер для анонимного доступа к файлам nas через web интерфейс. Чтобы по адресу к приставке в браузере можно было просматривать и скачивать файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, кто такой Arabian, подозреваю арабская версия андроид. Так вот, на андроиде легко поднять FTP-сервер (как, впрочем, и на любой другой ОС). Есть как [специализированное ПО](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ftp%20server&c=apps), так и функции в файловых менеджерах. Например в [CX explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cxinventor.file.explorer)

Comment: Опечатался, извините. Исправил.